# Why does referencing a Bool give warning

Tags: ios

Learning ios programming, please clarify why a reference to a Boolean type will give me a warning but a variable created with the property of a boolean type will not have any warnings?

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL *userTyped; //-> userTyped is pointer to BOOL type


-(IBAction) button:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.userTyped = YES; //-> will give a warning saying assigning char to BOOL
}
```

---

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userTyped; //-> userTyped acts as variable of BOOl type

-(IBAction) button:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.userTyped = YES; //-> this will not give warning.
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: In your first example, `userTyped` is a pointer to a boolean. Thus, `self.userTyped = YES` means that you want to set the pointer, itself, to be `YES`. That makes no sense, and thus why the compiler is complaining. I suspect that this represents a significant confusion between dealing with objects (which generally use the `*` pointer syntax) and primitive data types (which generally don't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BOOL *` is a pointer to a Boolean. Don't do that please. `BOOL` ain't an object. If you want to set it as `self.userTyped = YES`, then simply use `BOOL` and not `BOOL *`.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
self.userType = YES;
```

you are attempting to set a pointer to a `BOOL` to a `BOOL` value in the first example. You need to set it to a pointer to a `BOOL`, or change the type from `BOOL*` to `BOOL`.

Comment: After the first piece of advice, I imagine OP's next question: "what if `BOOL *b = malloc(sizeof(BOOL));` returns `NULL`?"...

Comment: It's a fair question. :-) But it doesn't have to be an allocation. It could be an assignment to an existing pointer, too. Since he doesn't say what he's trying to do, it's hard to give reasonable advice.

Comment: @userXXX yep, but what if next time he'll take the address of a local variable? Uhhh, stack smashing incoming...

Comment: @H2CO3 In no way am I suggesting that anything you're saying is wrong. It's probably not what he wants in this case and might even be dangerous here, but again, this example may not really be what he's getting at. Conceptually, if you have a pointer, you need to assign a pointer value to it, and you if you have a regular old type, you need to assign a value of that type to it. That's all I wanted to get across, because this won't be the last time he runs into this, and it can be helpful to understand why it's happening, not just that he's doing it wrong in this particular case.

Comment: @userXXX Of course, neither do I suggest that it's incorrect that you wrote. It's just rare to use a BOOL pointer. I am not splitting hair, I just don't want another segfault master in the iOS developer community in the person of OP...